# Qualification needed for understanding Bhagavad Gita as it is

Tags: bhagavad-gita, gita

What are the qualifications one need to understand Bhagavad Gita as it is?

Because I have seen many people in first impression misunderstood Gita as it is, and people have much confusion regarding it.

What does the Acharyas says about qualifications to understand Bhagavad Gita? What are qualifications according to Bhagavad Gita one need to read or understanding? Is association of pure devotees required or pious Karma needed to best read it? Or is mercy of Shri Krishna required to truly appreciate it?

Comment: BG As It Is - is purely a Dvaita rendition (as far as I have seen).  There's no pre-qualification for understanding BG. A simple surrender will do. The best way to understand it is - picking any random verse, contemplating deeply on it and observing it within and around us till it sinks in. Once we repeat this exercise 2-3 times, we are good to understand the entire BG.

Comment: It's an opinion based question. The Lord says *sarva dharman parityajya, mamekam sharnam vraj*, complete surrender to the Supreme is a way to the Divine and their teachings.